# Getting Current Date and Return as Integer?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a date like this (mm/yy) in row 1
`A    B    C    D    E    F 
1/19 2/19 3/19 4/19 5/19 6/19 ...`

I want the VBA to recognize today's date and match it to current column and return as integer.
Ignoring the days (only matching month and year).

For example, if today is **4/13/2019**, it would be **4** (column D)

I would need this in VBA because I will be using it to define a range:
`For today To x month`

Comment: Use `match`. Are the dates in row 1 actual dates formatted to show mm/yy or have they been entered as text?

Comment: it's in dd/mm/yyyy but format to show like mm/yy

Comment: Then simply something like `application.match(CLng(Date), Rows(1), 0)`

Comment: @Rory, So i put `Range("A2") = Application.Match(CLng(Date), Rows(1), 0)`  I get N/A...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It appears OP was looking for a VBA solution, so here is an alternative.

I can think of a few completely different methods of accomplishing this within VBA. Your question isn't very clear of what you are wanting the end result to be, but it appears you are looking for a function that will return the column number - perhaps so you can use to pinpoint a range.

```
Function DateCol(ByVal InputDate As Date) As Long

    Dim colDate As Date
    colDate = InputDate - Day(InputDate) + 1

    Dim srcRng As Range
    Set srcRng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(1)

    DateCol = srcRng.Find(What:=colDate, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column

End Function
```

You simply take an input date, subtract the days (and add 1 since the first day of the month isn't `0`). Then you take this new date and use the `.Find()` method to locate the range that contains your date on the worksheet, and finally the `.Column` property to get the number you are looking for.

Here is a small sample usage:

```
Sub test()

    ' Example Usage
    Cells(10, DateCol(#6/11/2019#)).Value = "Test"

End Sub
```

In the above test sub, the `DateCol()` function would have returned the value of `6` in your sample worksheet, making the result:

```
Cells(10, 6).Value = "Test"
```

---

Only issue is that this function doesn't contain any error handling. You will raise an error if the date is not found in `.Find()`, so ensure that you take this into consideration.

Also, don't forget to change this line to use the true Worksheet:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(1)
```

Comment: Can we use EOMONTH function for the dates?

Comment: I suppose you could use `colDate = WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(InputDate, -1) + 1` instead of `colDate = InputDate - Day(InputDate) + 1`, but not really sure if it would really make much of a difference.

Comment: So with this the DateCol will return a value (integer)? So I can use it like this `For DateCol to DateCol + 6` basically range from today to 6 months out (6/19 ~ 1/20)

Comment: Yes that is correct. But it requires an argument, the date. `For i = DateCol(Date) To DateCol(Date) + 6`. Not only is `Date` a data type, it’s also a VBA function that returns today’s date, same as the worksheet function `Today()`.

Answer (score -2):

I had to redo my answer after messing with the data. this is what i ended up with.

On Row 1 I entered the dates as: 1/1/2019, 2/1/2019, 3/1/2019... and custom formatted the row to only show it as mm/yy.

With the formula below I grab the month and year from the given date and convert it into the first of the month. I am very positive there is a better way to make it but my brain is fried for the day.

`=MATCH(NUMBERVALUE(TEXT(A3,"mm")&"/1/"&TEXT(A3,"yy")),$1:$1,0)`

Edit: (Edit formula to make it permanent on Row 1 [$1:$1])

Assuming that the date 4/13/2019 is on Cell A3

[image]

Comment: I think the easier way to do it is `=MATCH(A3,$1:$1,1)`, since the dates are in ascending order.

Comment: 4/13/2019 is just an example. Need to go off of today's date 6/11/2019 (today's date should be baked into a formula). And returns 6, column F